# How to programmatically customize editform.aspx/newform.aspx with SP2007?

Tags: sharepoint

I have been looking for a solution for hours but I can't manage to customize my list forms. Although it is very easy to modify the form under SPDesigner, I can't find a way to do the same in VS2008.

Does anyone know the way to customize a form programmatically ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The best way to customize newform.asxp and editform.aspx (in my opinion) could be  :

On a new visual studio solution :

- Define your content type for the list
- Define a list shema based on the CT
- In the section "forms" in the schema.xml define your own aspx for editform.aspx and newform.aspx like

  ```
  <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\YourListDefinitionPathInSolution\YourEditForm.aspx" UseLegacyForm="True" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\YourListDefinitionPathInSolution\YourEditForm.aspx" UseLegacyForm="True"  WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  </Forms>
  ```

In this blog post you will find the good recipe : [Create custom SharePoint 2010 list form for deployment in a Visual Studio 2010 project](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/)

Regards

EDIT : sorry, recipe for 2010 version :-(

Answer (score -1):

What you are suggesting does not sound like best practice, the newform.aspx, editform.aspx, etc. are the SharePoint out-of-the-box forms for the list and should probably be left alone.

What changes are you making? Simple changes like increasing the size of text boxes or substantial changes?

You can create your own forms if the changes are substantial

Comment: Small changes like inserting text between fields etc... I have tried to create new forms via designer but I can't manage to use new forms created programmatically

Comment: I think it is in the content type definition where you state what forms to use in edit mode and display mode - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543904

Comment: Customizing the NewForm and EditForms is both acceptable and common.